# Blurry display with HDMI-to-VGA adapter

Tags: windows, hdmi, vga

I have an older LCD monitor (Eizo FlexScan L568) with two inputs: one DVI input and one VGA input. I have previously used the VGA input with my work computer which had a VGA port. I have had no issues with the display quality. Unfortunately, my new work computer (Dell Latitude 5521) has no VGA port so I bought a HDMI-to-VGA adapter; a no-name HDMI A M to VGA F.

With the adapter the display is slightly blurry despite setting the display resolution to the native monitor resolution (1280x1024) and setting scaling to 100% in Windows 10. I have also tried to set the resolution to 1280x720 which should be pixel perfect but it is just as blurry.

Is there any additional setting I have forgotten, is the adapter defect or just low quality, or is this what I can expect from a HDMI-to-VGA converter?

Comment: If the monitor has one DVI input you should have definitely used that along with a simple HDMI-DVI adapter, no conversion needed, digital signal on both end, they just work. HDMI to D-sub always implies active circuitry to convert digital to analog video with all the potential issues it implies. Some converters do a good enough job, others (many) are crap.

Comment: Yeah DVI-D to HDMI is passthrough, but there do exist DVI-I single/double and DVI-A. I think DVI-I should still be OK, DVI-A would require conversion. a quick look at specs for the monitor suggest it is DVI-D. DVI should be the preferred connection

Comment: @ChanganAuto I already use the DVI input with my home computer so that is not an option.

Comment: If DVI isn't an option then get yourself a better HDMI-VGA adapter or a modern monitor.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So you imply that there are indeed HDMI-to-VGA adapters which can perform pixel perfect conversion to 1280x1024? How do I know if a given adapter can do that?

Comment: I'm not implying nor could I because I never used such things. It has been reported - you can use Google the same way I can - that some do a good enough job while others are just crap (most no-name cheap ones probably fall into this category). Nothing else to add, do your own research based on trustworthy reviews.

Comment: How long is your HDMI cable? I've seen similar results with signal degradation on 2 metre HDMI cables even without using adaptors, especially on cheaper cables.

Comment: @AndyHames The converter cable is only one decimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by pressing the **Auto Adjustment Button** on my monitor (a button marked "A"). According to the manual it adjusts the clock, phase, screen position and resolution. Now the display is sharp again.

Comment: Amazing! Nice to know even old monitors have some decent features in them. Congrats on getting this to work.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks! In rare cases the solution is only a button press away.